# Why isn't my web page transition working? (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="myLink" href="#">
            Click to slide in new page
    </a>


<iframe id="newPage" src="http://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>
</body> 
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
 #myLink {
 position: absolute;
}

iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 100%;    
 position: fixed;
 background-color: blue;

}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$("#myLink").click(function () {
$('#newPage').transition({top: '0%' });
});
```

I am literally copy and pasting from this source http://jsfiddle.net/TheGAFF/hNYMr/ to achieve a transition between web pages using iframe but for some reason when I try this simple code in my browser, it doesn't work. I can't see why this doesn't work in my browser when I link it to index.html. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Edit: The "#myLink" in the CSS page isn't commented out, it just happened to format like this in the question.

Comment: Look in the F12 Console for errors/missing resources

Comment: Use [`<!-- language: lang-css -->`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code in the question as CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look in your JavaScript console**. Expect to see an error about `$` not being defined.

See this code:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First you load your script, which tries to use `$`. **Then** you try to load jQuery, which defines `$`.

Swap the order or your script elements.

---

You then have a second problem.

```
$("#myLink")
```

You have no element with `id="myLink"` in the document at the time the script runs.

It doesn't get added to the DOM until 4 lines later.

Either:

- move the script so it appears after the elements you are trying to access
- use an event handler (like DOM Ready):

Such:

```
$( function () {
    $("#myLink").click(function () {
        $('#newPage').transition({top: '0%' });
    });
} );
```

- use delegated events

Such:

```
$(document).on("click", "#myLink", function () {
    $('#newPage').transition({top: '0%' });
});
```

Comment: Okay so I swapped the order of my jQuery library script and my main.js script and I used the delegated events that you described (copied your code) but it still isn't working like the JSFiddle? Are there any other problems? Thank you so much by the way. I never realized the implications of the order of this code :D. The function is called when the link is clicked (I tried it with alert("hi");), so I guess the problem is with the $('#newPage').transition({top: '0%'}); part?

Comment: I used the F12 console. It says that $(...).transition is not a function. I thought it was a function of jQuery? How come the guy in the JSFiddle can use it but it doesn't work here?

Comment: Because it isn't part of core jQuery and you didn't load all the JS files that you did on JSFiddle.  https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPsAI1Na5JCWZCT6YCto7-_DgnHeLjBfA4B/image.png

Comment: IT WORKED WHEN I CHANGED THE FUNCTION "transition" to "animate". I guess the guy in the JSFiddle was using a different version of jQuery or something. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit; sorry you already did that.

Try puttting your js file Under the js library file.